# How can I make a circle from grid of GameObjects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, geometry, trigonometry

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:
[image]

What I have so far is the edges for the circles.

[image: Expected Results]

I know this would involve a nested for loop. This is what I have so far:

```
public GameObject player;
private GameObject playerGrid;

public int numOfObjects;
private Vector3 centerPos;
public int size = 2;

public Vector2 speed = new Vector2(50, 50);
private float smoothTime = 0.25f;

void Start()
{
    playerGrid = new GameObject();
    centerPos = transform.position;

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfObjects; i++)
    {
        float pointNum = (i * 1.0f) / numOfObjects;
        float angle = pointNum * Mathf.PI * 2;
        float r = size / 2 * (Mathf.PI); 
        float x = Mathf.Sin(angle) * r;
        float y = Mathf.Cos(angle) * r;
        Vector3 pointPos = new Vector3(x, y, 0) + centerPos;
        GameObject obj = Instantiate(player, pointPos, Quaternion.identity);
        obj.transform.SetParent(playerGrid.transform);
    }        
}
```

I am stuck on how to implement the conditional for the nested for loop. Also, I have trouble understanding the calculations of column positions in the nested for loop. I believe the conditional would be the start and end of I for that column or row: for(int j = i + 1; j < i - 1, j++)

For the col positions, I would think it would be incrementing the angle enough to give the square its space for that column: float x = (Mathf.Sin(angle) + somethingHere) * r;

I just not sure how to progress from here.

Comment: Actually you would rather run through a grid (2 loops) and check whether you are inside the circle or not

Comment: Fair point but how do I get the square's positioning so that they don't overlap? The squares need to be dynamic in pixel unit sizes for my game. @derHugo

Comment: Well just like in the image you posted: You just make sure you place them always 1 unit apart from each other .. so if your square size grows also the grid size grows accordingly

Comment: Okay, I'll post the solution once I type it up.

Comment: What values are given? Circle radius? Number of objects? Object size (for square object)?

Comment: Let's say it's a 4X4 grid, so Circle radius would probably be 2, number of objects 16, and object size is 1-pixel per unit @MBo

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to draw a circle:

```
public float circleRadius = 5f;
public float objectSize = 1f;

void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    for (var x = -circleRadius; x <= circleRadius; x++)
    {
        for (var y = -circleRadius; y <= circleRadius; y++)
        {
            var pos = new Vector3(x, 0f, y);
            
            if (pos.magnitude >= circleRadius) continue;

            Gizmos.DrawSphere(pos * (objectSize * 2f), objectSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I add a box collider to this? @Iggy I need a way to check if my squares are within my circle.

Comment: @HakeemThomas This is a gizmo example. In your project instead of drawing gizmos, you would instantiate a game object, that would have the box collider attached. You could always just do a simple `pos.magnitude < x` check to see if the box is within the circle. You could also utilize the `Physics.OverlapSphere` for more advanced detection.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am close to finishing. I have a line renderer circle with box collision. I will see about magnitude.

Comment: Magnitude works but there is a problem. It seems the calculations go wrong for some units with the same values(I.E: Working points [(-1.5, 0.5), (1.5, -0.5)] Doesn't Work Points[(-0.5, 1.5), (0.5, 1.5)]).

Comment: @HakeemThomas sorry I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: You gave me the correct answer with magnitude. I can answer the question now.